# Find an alternative FPTAS for knapsack

Tags: polynomials, linear-programming, recursive-algorithms, integer-programming

There is a famous algorithm using, the recusive integer data problem on:

w(j,p) = min weight set of items of profit=p when we have j items

Now I was wondering if there was an alternative solution using:

p(j,w) = max profit set of items of weight=k when we have j items

The recursion can be found without so much difficulty; $p(j,w) = max(p(j-1,w), p(j-1,w-w_j)+p_j$)

$p(.,0)=0\\
p(.,w<0)=-\infty\\
p(0,w>0) = -\infty$

Thank you for your help or if you can redirect me to a paper dealing with it :).

Comment: What is FPTAS ?

Comment: Fully Polynomial-time approximation scheme